# Add n progressbars dynamically in android

Tags: android

i have this code:

```
private void addPartiesBar(ArrayList<PoliticalPartyModel> partyModelArrayList) {
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraintProgressBar);
    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
    int voteBarId = 1000;


                                         //has 3 entries
    for (PoliticalPartyModel singlePartyModel : partyModelArrayList) {
        ProgressBar voteBar = new ProgressBar(this/*, null, android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Horizontal*/);
        voteBarId++;
        voteBar.setId(voteBarId);

        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);
        layoutParams.startToStart = PARENT_ID;
        layoutParams.endToEnd = PARENT_ID;
        voteBar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        constraintLayout.addView(voteBar, 0);

        set.clone(constraintLayout);
        set.connect(voteBarId, ConstraintSet.TOP, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 100);
    }
    set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
}
```

it should looks like this:

[image]

but looks like this :/

[image]

What did I wrong? **Why it shows only 2 progressbars?** All the progressbars (the progressbar above is a little bit thicker) are at position 1. Sorry for my very bad english. I hope you know what I want :)

---

With the answer from Dak28 it works like a charm. But i cant set the height of the progressbar.

[image]

Comment: Why do you use a constraint layout and not a LinearLayout ? If I was you I will add a LinearLayout (with orientation vertical) below the grey text and then create and add the progressBar. 
And the progressBar are a little bit custom, it can be easier to create a custom view and add it

Comment: This is a nice Idea. How can I do that? I cant style the progressbar at my wishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ProgressBar voteBar = new ProgressBar(this/*, null, 
                      android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Horizontal*/);
```

Why did you comment the horizontal style part?

Shouldn't be like this?

```
  ProgressBar voteBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, 
                      android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Horizontal);
```

To create horizontal style use this code, i didn't edit too much the style:

```
for(x in 0..3) {

        var voteBar =
            ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal)

        val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            400, // whatever value you need
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )

        voteBar.isIndeterminate = false
        voteBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        voteBar.progress = 50

        linearLayout.addView(voteBar)
    }
```

**I didn't add id but if you add id you can change value by acced progress field**

Comment: It should just take the correct style.
If you need to put consecutive three bars is it strictly necessary use constrainst layout? couldn't be use a linear layout se you just need to add stuff?

The linear layout can be then nested in a constarinst layout if you need put tem somewhere

Comment: This is a nice idea. I dont think about this. How can I do that?

Comment: I will post soon answer :)

Comment: Im having probelm in create custom attribute set, you do not see the bar because of that null, that has to be replaced somehow, im checking out